# Requirements for launching Google Cloud AI Platform Notebooks with custom docker image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

On AI Platform Notebooks, [the UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/mlengine/notebooks/create-instance) lets you select a custom image to launch. If you do so, you're greeted with an info box saying that the container "must follow certain technical requirements":

[image: certain technical requirements]

I assume this means they have a required entrypoint, exposed port, jupyterlab launch command, or *something*, but I can't find any documentation of what the requirements actually *are*.

I've been trying to reverse engineer it without much luck. I `nmap`ed a standard instance and saw that it had port 8080 open, but setting my image's `CMD` to run Jupyter Lab on `0.0.0.0:8080` did not do the trick. When I click "Open JupyterLab" in the UI, I get a 504.

Does anyone have a link to the relevant docs, or experience with doing this in the past?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can create custom containers:

## Building a Derivative Container

If you only need to install additional packages, ou should create a Dockerfile derived from one of the standard images (for example, FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu.1-13:latest), then add RUN commands to install packages using conda/pip/jupyter.

The conda base environment has already been added to the path, so no need to conda init/conda activate unless you need to setup another environment. Additional scripts/dynamic environment variables that need to be run prior to bringing up the environment can be added to /env.sh, which is sourced as part of the entrypoint.

For example, let’s say that you have a custom built TensorFlow wheel that you’d like to use in place of the built-in TensorFlow binary. If you need no additional dependencies, your Dockerfile will be similar to:

Dockerfile.example

```
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu:latest
RUN pip uninstall -y tensorflow-gpu && \
    pip install -y /path/to/local/tensorflow.whl
```

Then you’ll need to build and push it somewhere accessible to your GCE service account.

```
PROJECT="my-gcp-project"
docker build . -f Dockerfile.example -t "gcr.io/${PROJECT}/tf-custom:latest"
gcloud auth configure-docker
docker push "gcr.io/${PROJECT}/tf-custom:latest"
```

## Building Container From Scratch

The main requirement is that the container must expose a service on port 8080.

The sidecar proxy agent that executes on the VM will ferry requests to this port only.

If using Jupyter, you should also make sure your jupyter_notebook_config.py is configured as such:

```
c.NotebookApp.token = ''
c.NotebookApp.password = ''
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8080
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin_pat = (
'(^https://8080-dot-[0-9]+-dot-devshell\.appspot\.com$)|'
'(^https://colab\.research\.google\.com$)|'
'((https?://)?[0-9a-z]+-dot-datalab-vm[\-0-9a-z]*.googleusercontent.com)')
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = False
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/home'
```

This disables notebook token-based auth (auth is instead handled through oauth login on the proxy), and allows cross origin requests from three sources: Cloud Shell web preview, colab (see this blog post), and the Cloud Notebooks service proxy. Only the third is required for the notebook service; the first two support alternate access patterns.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extensive answer! Was this online somewhere that I missed or is this as-yet undocumented?

Comment: This a draft version of a document we'll be releasing soon :)

Comment: Great. One question: in the base image there is a Jupyter serverextension called `jupyter_aihub_deploy_extension` which seems not to be publicly available. Is this required?

Comment: No, I don't believe so

Comment: For running notebooks from AI Hub to custom instances how can we install jupyter_aihub_deploy_extension ?

Comment: FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cpu
FROM <your container>

COPY --from=0 /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_aihub_deploy_extension /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_aihub_deploy_extension
RUN pip install requests

pip install -U jupyterlab
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_aihub_deploy_extension

Answer (score 1):

To complete Zain's answer, below you can find a minimal example using official Jupyter image, inspired by this repo https://github.com/doitintl/AI-Platform-Notebook-Using-Custom-Container:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook:python-3.9.5

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip", "0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "--config", "/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py"]

COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /etc/jupyter/
```

`jupyter_notebook_config.py`

(almost the same as Zain's, but with an extra pattern enabling the communication with the kernel; the communication didn't work without it)

```py
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.token = ''
c.NotebookApp.password = ''
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8080
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin_pat = '(^https://8080-dot-[0-9]+-dot-devshell\.appspot\.com$)|(^https://colab\.research\.google\.com$)|((https?://)?[0-9a-z]+-dot-datalab-vm[\-0-9a-z]*.googleusercontent.com)|((https?://)?[0-9a-z]+-dot-[\-0-9a-z]*.notebooks.googleusercontent.com)|((https?://)?[0-9a-z\-]+\.[0-9a-z\-]+\.cloudshell\.dev)|((https?://)ssh\.cloud\.google\.com/devshell)'
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = False
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/home'
c.Session.debug = True
```

And finally, think about this page while troubleshooting: https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting